# QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message. Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, quickbooks

I am integrating QuickBooks Desktop Enterprise 2013 with a web app using the Web Connector version 2.1.0.30 as an intermediary.
The SOAP service I developed with WCF in Visual Studio Core, and the Web Connector accesses without problems to my services, here I show the execution log of the web connector

> Blockquote
>   20170811.21:39:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'WCService' has STARTED
>   20170811.21:39:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
>   20170811.21:39:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
>   20170811.21:39:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
>   20170811.21:39:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
>   20170811.21:39:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: WCService
>   20170811.21:39:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): WCService
>   20170811.21:39:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: http://localhost:14319/WCService.svc
>   20170811.21:39:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() :  Calling serverVersion().
>   20170811.21:39:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Received from serverVersion() following parameter:
>   20170811.21:39:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() :  Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:
>   20170811.21:39:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : Received from clientVersion() following parameter:
>   20170811.21:39:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application agrees with the current version of QBWebConnector. Allowing update operation.
>   20170811.21:39:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'WCService', username = 'Dalo'
>   20170811.21:39:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:
>   **20170811.21:39:28 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
>   Índice fuera de los límites de la matriz.**
>   More info:
>   StackTrace =    en QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
>   Source = QBWebConnector
>   20170811.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
>   20170811.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
>   20170811.21:39:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
>   Blockquote

Now I show you my QWC file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBWCXML>
  <AppDescription>QB Web Service</AppDescription>
  <AppID></AppID>
  <AppName>WCService</AppName>
  <AppSupport>http://localhost:14319/WCService.svc?wsdl</AppSupport>
  <AppURL>http://localhost:14319/WCService.svc</AppURL>
  <FileID>{CA1C3EB8-1B61-4747-A743-8D5B438B83AC}</FileID>
  <OwnerID>{8C809D2B-69A9-4B43-A9D0-D41C0938368B}</OwnerID>  
  <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
  <Style>Document</Style>
  <UserName>Dalo</UserName>
</QBWCXML>
```

Then the service code:

```
public string[] authenticate(string strUserName, string strPassword)
    {
        string evLogTxt = "WebMethod: authenticate() has been called by QBWebconnector" + "\r\n\r\n";
        evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "Parameters received:\r\n";
        evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "string strUserName = " + strUserName + "\r\n";
        evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "string strPassword = " + strPassword + "\r\n";
        evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "\r\n";


        string[] authReturn = new string[3];
        // Code below uses a random GUID to use as session ticket
        // An example of a GUID is {85B41BEE-5CD9-427a-A61B-83964F1EB426}
        authReturn[0] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // For simplicity of sample, a hardcoded username/password is used.
        // In real world, you should handle authentication in using a standard way. 
        // For example, you could validate the username/password against an LDAP 
        // or a directory server
        string pwd = "password";
        evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "Password locally stored = " + pwd + "\r\n";
        if (strUserName.Trim().Equals("Dalo") && strPassword.Trim().Equals(pwd))
        {
            // An empty string for authReturn[1] means asking QBWebConnector 
            // to connect to the company file that is currently openned in QB
            authReturn[1] = "C:\\Users\\Dalo\\Documents\\company.QBW";                
            authReturn[2] = "10";                
        }
        else
        {
            authReturn[1] = "nvu";
            authReturn[2] = "";                
        }
        // You could also return "none" to indicate there is no work to do
        // or a company filename in the format C:\full\path\to\company.qbw
        // based on your program logic and requirements.

        evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "\r\n";
        evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "Return values: " + "\r\n";
        evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "string[] authReturn[0] = " + authReturn[0].ToString() + "\r\n";
        evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "string[] authReturn[1] = " + authReturn[1].ToString();
        logEvent(evLogTxt);
        return authReturn;
    }
```

Other data:

1. The authenticate service was tested with the Visual Studio WCF Test Client tool.
2. In code debugging, when the authentication fails, the web connector calls neither the connectionError service nor the closeConnection to terminate the connection.
3. In debugging the code, you can see that the whole code of the authenticate service is run without throwing any exceptions.

This's response

```xml
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <s:Body>
            <authenticateResponse xmlns="http://developer.intuit.com/">
                <authenticateResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <a:string>bd68a1e2-7780-46ed-bb8a-09b2b25e156f</a:string>
                    <a:string>C:\Users\Dalo\Documents\company.QBW</a:string>
                </authenticateResult>
            </authenticateResponse>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem while trying to build the web service in Go, and Intuits QBWC documentation seems to be pretty outdated and incomplete.  I found that this soap 1.2 version seems to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
          <soap12:Body>
            <authenticateResponse xmlns="http://developer.intuit.com/">
              <authenticateResult>
                <string>123a</string>
                <string></string>
              </authenticateResult>
            </authenticateResponse>
          </soap12:Body>
        </soap12:Envelope>
```

This was found here:
https://test.developer.intuit.com/QBWC/TroubleshootWebServiceFS/Service.asmx